# Move Up columns DataFrame Pandas to where rows match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I didn't really know how to ask this question so don't hate me if there is already an answer.

I have a `DataFrame f`. It contains meteorology data, more specifically temperature data. The column names for the temperature data are:

```
['tmp_m', 'tmpsfc', 'Maximum_temperature_height_above_ground_Mixed_intervals_Maximum', 'Minimum_temperature_height_above_ground_Mixed_intervals_Minimum']
```

I have a 'z' column that can specify elevation in meters. If the elevation is not specified then the value in this column is nan.

I also have a 'time' columns that is a DateTime column.

The main issue that I have is that the DataFrame when it was created, not by me, was not done by inner_joining on time, but on another column and so I can have the same time for the 4 temperature data columns, but have these on different rows and so when one temperature data column has a value for a time at a specific row the other temperature data columns are nan, except for the last 2 temperature data columns since they were initially joined on time as they come from the same source. See the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I would like to do and very efficiently is:

1. Go from long to wide format by creating new columns if latitude is specified so for example, if I have tmp_m variable at 2 meters and at 80 meters. I transform the column tmp_m to 2 columns one is tmp_m_2m and the other is tmp_m_80m
2. "Squish" the DataFrame so that the temperature data columns are "joined" on time

I think bullet point 1 can be done by googling long to wide, but I have no idea what to even google for bullet point 2

Please help all mighty SO gods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, if I understand correctly, you have multiple rows for the same `time` values such that either the first, second or last 2 temp columns are populated and the remaining are nulls. And you want to squish the df such that you don't have multiple records for the same `time` value and all temp columns are populated for each row.

If that is the case, the following approach might work:

- Create three df subsets like this:

  1. One with only the first temp column (out of 4 temp columns) and all the other columns.
  2. One with only the second temp column and all the other columns.
  3. One with only the last 2 temp columns and all the other columns.
- For all three dfs, drop rows where the temp column in that df is null.
- Join the resulting dfs on time.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. I know I can do that, but that is not very efficient :)

Comment: Can you explain which step exactly is inefficient?